# Cancellation of certificate of course completion

Tags: united-kingdom, online-degree

I took a 4-month online course in London. Upon completion, I received an email congratulating me for passing the course with the course certificate attached. The following day, I was told that there was a mistake in the grade given and that I did not pass the course. There is no plagiarism involved. Is it legal to revoke the certificate and change the grade from pass to fail?

Comment: For legal questions, consult a professional.  Personally, I doubt such cancelation was illegal.

Answer (score 4):

It would be normal procedure for an institution to correct a grade if an error is found afterward, no matter whether the new grade was higher or lower, and no matter if the student had already been issued a certificate.  The goal is to "get it right".

The institution may have internal time limits as to when this can be done, or how much internal review is required, but those limits would typically be months to years.  One day is practically no time at all on academic time scales.

Of course, if you think the newly assigned grade is not actually correct, you probably have a right to appeal or request a review.  You would have to refer to the policies of your institution to find out how to go about that.  But if you acknowledge that the new grade is correct and the original one wasn't, there isn't really anything to be done.

Legal questions are outside the scope of this site, but since this is common practice, I would be very surprised if it is illegal in any country.

It is certainly unfortunate and frustrating that the mistake was made, but at the end of the day, the grade is what it is.  I wish you better success going forward!